# How to decide/querying data based on several criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have table: `servers` that contain list of my server.

```
---+--------------+---------+----------+
id |  disk_space  | memory  | cpu_core |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 1 |      100000  |  2048   |   1      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 2 |      200000  |  1024   |   2      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 3 |      200000  |  2048   |   1      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 4 |      100000  |  2048   |   2      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
```

How can I get the best server based on that specs (has many maximum value)?.

For above example, I need to get record with `id=3` because has max value in two fields(disk_space and memory).

### Case 2

```
---+--------------+---------+----------+
id |  disk_space  | memory  | cpu_core |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 1 |      100000  |  2048   |   1      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 2 |      200000  |  4096   |   4      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 3 |      200000  |  2048   |   2      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
 4 |      400000  |  2048   |   2      |
---+--------------+---------+----------+
```

This should return row with id=2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right syntax but this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY disc_space DESC,memory DESC,cpu_core DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that query not accommodate cpu_core field

Comment: @Habibillah what do you mean? You told that id=3 is your preferred output with the most disc_space and memory

Comment: Yes, id=3 is preferred because that has max value in two fields. if there is a record that has max value in 3 fields, that should be a choice.

Comment: Ah.., Sorry if my question is weird and make you confused. But your answer is just to sort it by disk_space, if there a duplicate/same value in disk_space sort it by memory field, and so..

my question is selecting a record that has max value in most field. See case 2 above. You answer will fail.

Comment: In case 2 why return id=2 ? 400000 is greater than 200000

Comment: because has greater value in two fields. memory and cpu_core. id=4 just have greater value in one field.

Answer (score 0):

I work on DB2 so you probably will need to refactor this for MYSQL, but this would do it on DB2:

```
with CTE_MAX_VALUES as (

select max( DISK_SPACE ) as MAX_DISK_SPACE
      ,max( MEMORY )     as MAX_MEMORY
      ,max( CPU_CORE )   as MAX_CPU_CODE
from   SERVERS
)

select     SERVERS.*
from       CTE_MAX_VALUES
cross join SERVERS
order by   case when DISK_SPACE = MAX_DISK_SPACE then 1 else 0 end +
           case when MEMORY     = MAX_MEMORY     then 1 else 0 end +
           case when CPU_CORE   = MAX_CPU_CORE   then 1 else 0 end desc
fetch      first row only
```

You didn't mention how a tie should be handled. In the case of a tie, if for example a certain max column should be selected before the others, you could handle that with an enhanced order by:

```
order by   case when DISK_SPACE = MAX_DISK_SPACE then 1 else 0 end +
           case when MEMORY     = MAX_MEMORY     then 1 else 0 end +
           case when CPU_CORE   = MAX_CPU_CORE   then 1 else 0 end desc
          ,case when CPU_CORE   = MAX_CPU_CORE   then 1 else 0 end desc --tie - 1st choice
          ,case when MEMORY     = MAX_MEMORY     then 1 else 0 end desc --tie - 2nd choice 
          ,case when DISK_SPACE = MAX_DISK_SPACE then 1 else 0 end desc --tie - 3rd choice
```